# Picasso(загрузка изображение при запуске приложения)

Tags: android, picasso

Приложение должно загружать с сервера изображение и устанавливать его как Activity. Вот только изображение не успевает загрузиться и фон остается "по умолчанию"
В качестве фона у меня выступает `ImageView` и в методе `OnCreate` я его инициализирую

```
fon = new ImageView(this);
```

и после чего пытаюсь установить в него изображение:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL_BACKGROUND).into(fon);
```

Вот только Picasso загружает его уже после того как метод `onCreate` отработал и `fon` не меняется

**UDP:**

Есть еще вот такой вариант подгрузки изображения и установки его в качестве фонa:

```
mTarget = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    contentNav = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_navigation_drawer);
                    contentNav.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap));

                }
                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                }
            };

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL_BACKGROUND).into(mTarget);
```

Только тут в качестве фон выступает `RelativeLayout` и при  этом всё равно, изображение подгружается сильно поздно и в `runtime` не изменятся а лишь после того как будет снова вызван `mTarget = new Target()`

Comment: Вы `ImageView` создание программно, я не знаю, прокатит ли это, но вроде, нужно либо в xml создавать либо программно, но ещё что-то нужно. Кто опытнее - поправьте меня

Comment: Таки да - если в разметку не добавлен ImageView то ничего не отобразится. Хть мгновенно загружайте, хоть годами

Answer (score 1):

1) Вы можете создать класс `public class App extends Application` и прописать в манифесте его

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_ico"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        **android:name=".App"**
        >
```

2) Внутри этого класса, который будет загружаться ДО начала загрузки любого Активити, внутри onCreate вы можете скачать картинку и при получениии результата (успешного или нет) - запускать свою активность

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
    new DownloadImage().execute(imageUri);
}

 private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urlDisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mImage = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
                mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyLog", "Error when downloading image: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mImage;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            //тут сохраняем полученный рисунок (если есть) и стартуем активность
        }
    }
```

3. Важно помнить, что скачивание нельзя сделать в основном потоке. Также, при таком решении будет небольшая задержка отображения Активити (пока идёт скачивание).

   4. Также, можно сделать промежуточную активность, которая будет загружать картинку.
   5. Сохранённую картинку подставляйте в свою ImageView через Пикассо.
   6. Помните о том, что нужно удалить скачанную картинку, когда она вам больше будет не нужна.